# Check if not null or not 0 in Liquibase Precondition

Tags: java, liquibase, changeset, preconditions

I have currently an issue with liquibase preconditions.
I would like to insert something only if a precondition request does'nt answer 0 or null... I explain :

```
<changeSet id="myId" author="myName">
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <sqlCheck expectedResult=????>SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tableB WHERE column2 IS NOT NULL;
    </sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
<insert tableName="tableA">
    <column name="column1" valueComputed="(SELECT columnA FROM tableB WHERE columnB IS NOT NULL;)" />
    <column name="column2" valueComputed="(SELECT columnB FROM tableB WHERE columnB IS NOT NULL;)" />
</insert>
```

I would like for my changeSet to only be played if the first request give me a result. Is there a way to do that without a custom precondition ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

Liquibase provides the conditional preconditions and/or/not, which can be used with all other preconditions. In your case, wrap the `<sqlCheck>` with a `<not>`.

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <not>
        <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tableB WHERE column2 IS NOT NULL;</sqlCheck>
    </not>
</preConditions>
```

See also the [Preconditions documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html).