# How to check for a result of >0 in Liquibase precondition (SQL format)?

Tags: liquibase

In a Liquibase precondition, I need to check that the result of a query returns a count greater than 0. I know a precondition can be structured like this to check the result is 0:

```
-- precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE columnA LIKE '%foo%'
```

How do I express that precondition so that the migration only runs if there *are* values in `columnA` that contain `"foo"`?

Something like `expectedResult:>0`

Note that I need a solution that works with SQL format changesets. There is a `<NOT>` element for XML and JSON changesets, but the documentation doesn't show any support for it in SQL-formattes changesets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if not null or not 0 in Liquibase Precondition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133148/check-if-not-null-or-not-0-in-liquibase-precondition)

Comment: @RolandWeisleder I looked at that Q&A but it's specifically about the XML format. I didn't see an obvious way to translate that to SQL format changesets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Liquibase does not support `not` for formattedSQL changesets. You can tweak SQL query to match the expected pattern, e.g.:

```
--changeset foo:bar
--preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN"
     --precondition-sql-check expectedResult:f SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 FROM my_table;
--/preConditions
--comment "PreCondition works"
```

Comment: Shouldn't the expectedResult be `0`? My DB is MySQL if that makes a difference in how Liquibase treats 0/1 and boolean-type values.

Comment: I thought so as well. But I tested it, and it failed with an error like “expected 0, but instead got f”